# Object deletion from heap space

Tags: c++, heap-memory

In main function I create an object using new and don't delete it.I hope the heap space would be cleared once the process exits .The below is a sample code where object of class A is a  member variable of class B. Class B also has a multimap as a member variable.

```
    Class A
    {
    Public:
    A(); //have definition in cpp file
    ~A();//have definition in cpp file
    Private:
    Int a;
    };

    Class B{
    Private:
    Std::multimap<string,string> map_test;
    Public:
    A a;
    B(); //have definition inn cpp file
    ~B();//does not have any definition in cpp file
    };

    int main()
    {
      B *b = new B();
      /* code section where it fills some 1000 key value pairs in the multimap 
         for some purpose */
      return 0;

    }
```

My understanding:

1. Even if i do not delete the object here, it won't create any issue as the heap space would be cleaned once the process exits.As my scope of the programme is limited as above and nobody else is going to reuse this.So is it good or bad not to use delete? What's your suggestion on this?
2. It should call the object's default destructor which then calls the implicit multimap destructor. So its not needed to explicitly clear the multimap.Please correct me if i am wrong.
3. In parent class it just declares the destructor and does not have any definition.So will it call implicit destructor or it will ignore calling it?(There is no reason of not defining it, just asking for better understanding. )
4. If it calls implicit destructor in case of parent class, should it call the child class destructor which is defined here?
5. As the parent class object is instantiated using new, it would be created in heap.Then where exactly the member variables of this parent object would be stored.For example object "a" is a member variable and by looking into the declaration of this member object,  seems like it would be created in stack. I am just confused here how the parent object and its member child object exact memory creation happens. Can you please help me to understand this?

Comment: Edited: changed the derived/base to parent/child

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, as long as your object is created in main. 
   However, if you ever want to alter this and for example create multiple instances of B, or use it inside another class, etc etc etc, that's a different story. Also, memory checking tools like valgrind are going to give you false positives on a new w/o delete which you will be tempted to ignore. But then, you may ignore a true memory leak if it becomes a habit.
2. Correct, now if it was a `map<string, string*>` then you would likely need to clean up
3. It will call default destructor
4. Yes it will
5. I guess, you are asking where base class member variables are stored ? They are also stored on the heap. They precede derived class fields in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answers.I just edited the question and updated them as parent and child class instead derived and base class. But your answers make sense and i am clear on point num 5 now.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked many question.

First its best practice to alwsys clear your memory even if the process exits and clears all the memory ( as it does)  . Always handle it..its easy to do usining shared_ptr...

Destructors always get called in the right order however you multimap is a dangeorus as you should clear the elements in the multimap as ifyou store pointers it can cause a serious leak

Comment: Yes you are right :) I just posted all the questions those were coming into my mind. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: recently started using stackoverflow..i will be eligible to vote once i cross 15 reputation point :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Most OSs will clean up a process's heap space when the process exits. I wouldn't be surprised if there are a bunch of embedded OSs out there where that isn't the case, plus it is still bad practise as you do have a memory leak.
2. As you're leaking the memory, no destructors will be called. That said, if you're not implementing a destructor and rely on the compiler-generated default destructor, you should not declare it either - in fact I'm surprised that you're not getting a linker error. And yes, the default destructor for the multimap will delete the contents of the multimap as long as you observe the container's requirements for value semantics (ie, no raw pointers).
3. It is bad practise and as a programmer you should really make sure that you always manage your resources properly. Also, I don't see any reason for heap allocating `b`, you can just create the object on the stack and you won't have to think about resource management.
4. If you do declare it you'll have to provide an implementation as the declaration of the destructor will implicitly disable the compiler generated destructor. That's why I said above that I'm surprised you're not getting a link error.
5. The compiler will take care of the destruction of the base classes by walking the hierarchy and calling the destructors in reverse order of construction.
6. No, the whole object containing both A and B will be constructed on the heap - that's why you can alias a pointer to B as a pointer to A and interact with the derived class as if it was the base class.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting valuable points. I made a correction in my question, changed the derived/base to parent/child. Is this the reason i m not getting the linker error?

Comment: On point 3: If the class does have multimap like members, it may take more space. So should it be better to have it in heap?

Comment: The payload for the multimap is going to be allocated on the heap anyway in every implementation I'm aware of, so there is no need to allocate the multimap on the heap explicitly unless there is another good design reason.

Answer (score 0):

Fact : there's no native (under the table) garbage collection in C++, though there are many things that can enforce some sort of garbage collection.

Thus, in your code, you have a memory leak. At the end of the scope in which you allocate a B, the memory you allocated _is not *free'd*.

Going through your list of questions :

1. No, if you don't delete the pointer, the memory won't be free'd. There are a few things that you can do regarding this topic :

   - Use the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource acquisition is initialization), i.e. use objects to manage memory :
   - Use smart pointers : these constructs enforce RAII (the most common in my opinion being [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) and make sure the memory they are responsible for is correctly free'd.
2. It depends. If you allocated objects using the `new` operator, then inserted them in the map, but they aren't referenced anywhere else, then you should delete manually every entry of the map. It doesn't apply in this case because the map types aren't pointers.
3. The class could even omit a destructor declaration. If they are omitted, destructors (but also copy assignement operator, copy constructor and a default constructor) are generated by the compiler.
4. Edited: It depends, if you declared the member `A a;`, you don't have to explicitly delete it, its destructor will be called when the class that declares it as a member has its destructor called. but if it's a pointer that you allocated (e.g. in the constructor), then you have to delete it in the destructor.
5. Once you use dynamic memory allocation for an object, the *whole* object is on the heap, no matter how his members are declared.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Just on point 4, i had wrongly mentioned derived/base instead it should be parent/child. Just edited it.On point 1, i agree on using smart pointers is better approach. But just curious to know why the memory won't be freed once the process exits.Its the job of OS right?

Comment: @user2090833 Yes, modern OS will do that, but it's still bad practice. I edited my answer for your 4th question.